# git checkout error: invalid path 'app/code/Catwalk/Producteditor/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml '

Tags: git

I have cloned a repo in my windows machine. Clone is succeseded by during checkout it through a file path error with empty space at the end.

```
git checkout
error: invalid path 'app/code/Catwalk/Producteditor/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml '
```

Comment: what OS/File System is it?

Comment: I see it's wondows... what file system?

Comment: Could you tell us what path you have to the folder where you check it out?
In windows it might be a problem with the path length if the full path to the file ends up exceeding 260 characters.

Comment: I am clonig to /c/wamp/www/catwalk

Comment: my file system on C drive is ntfs

Comment: I don't know how relevant this is _but_ it does **look** so https://superuser.com/questions/738002/why-folder-or-file-name-in-windows-cannot-end-with-space

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+invalid+path

Answer (score 3):

```
'app/code/Catwalk/Producteditor/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml '
                                                        ^^^
```

You might need to rename the file on GitHub first (assuming this repository is cloned from Github) before being able to check it out locally: the trailing space to `routes.xml` means it cannot be created on a Windows file system.

See "[GitHub / Renaming a file](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-files/renaming-a-file)".